# Javascript regex for consective character checker and one exception

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to create a regex for a string with below criteria

Allowable characters:

- uppercase A to Z `A-Z`
- lowercase a to z `a-z`
- hyphen `` ` ``
- apostrophe `'`
- single quote `'`
- space
- full stop `.`
- numerals 0 to 9 `0-9`

Validations:

- Must start with an alphabetic character `a-zA-Z`
- Cannot have consecutive non-alpha characters except for a full stop followed by a space `.`

The regex I created

`` ^(?!.*[0-9'`\.\s-]{2})[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-`'.\s]+$ ``

Not sure how to put an exception to allow a full stop followed by a space. Please advise.

Comment: is full stop a period? can you provide example input (valid/invalid)?

Comment: @depperm "full stop" is what is used in the UK to mean a period.

Comment: Try this one: ``^(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*(?!\.\s)[\s`'.-]{2})[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.\s`'-]*$``. If you provide some example valid and invalid inputs, I could post an answer.

Comment: It can be shorter,  ``/^(?!.*(?!\.\s)[\s`'.-]{2})[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.\s`'-]*$/`` because the letter must be the first char and you require only one letter (other occurrences are optional).

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, just modified it a bit and now works, perfect.                ^(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*(?!\.\s)[0-9\s`'.-]{2})[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.\s`'-]*$

Comment: @user10118326 As I explained, you do not need the first `(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])` lookahead because it requires a letter, and the first consuming `[A-Za-z]` also requires a letter.

Answer (score 0):

1. *"Cannot have non-alphabetic characters at the start"*

- make sure that the string always starts with either **a-z** or **A-Z**
- [`(/^[a-zA-Z]+/).test(str)`](https://regex101.com/r/GlWgZ4/2)

2. *"Cannot have consecutive non-alpha characters **except for a full stop followed by a space**"*

- split at full-stop and space sequence ... `/(\.[ ]+)/`

3. *"**Cannot have consecutive non-alpha characters** except for a full stop followed by a space"*

- for every entry make sure that ...

  - it either equals ... `.`  ... "*except for a full stop followed by a space*"
  - or it matches ... [`/^((?<![-’'. 0-9])[-’'. 0-9]|[a-zA-Z]+)+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/GlWgZ4/1) ... *"Cannot have consecutive non-alpha characters"* (But can feature alphabetic sequences.)

    - for the non consecutiveness make use of a [negative lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) which ensures that specific non-alpha characters can not be preceded by their own kind.

```js
function validateString(str) {
  // [https://regex101.com/r/GlWgZ4/1]
  const regXSequence = (/^((?<![-’'. 0-9])[-’'. 0-9]|[a-zA-Z]+)+$/);
  str = String(str);
  return (
    // [https://regex101.com/r/GlWgZ4/2]
    (/^[a-zA-Z]+/).test(str) &&
    // split at full-stop and space sequence
    str.split(/(\.[ ]+)/).every(
      item => (item === '. ') || regXSequence.test(item)
    )
  );
}

console.log(
  '- Must contain alphabetic characters,\n- Cannot have non-alphabetic characters at the start,\n- Cannot have consecutive non-alpha characters except for a full stop followed by a space ...',
  validateString(
    "AaaaaAA'a'. a0a1a1aa. a0a1a.aa. a0a1a-aa. 0abc0a-b’c'dfhf.ejg f0a9sdfgjgjgkj"
  )
);
console.log(
  'Cannot have non-alphabetic characters at the start ...',
  validateString(
    " AaaaaAA'a'. a0a1a1aa. a0a1a.aa. a0a1a-aa. 0abc0a-b’c'dfhf.ejg f0a9sdfgjgjgkj"
  )
);
console.log(
  'Cannot have consecutive non-alpha characters except for a full stop followed by a space ...',
  validateString(
    "AaaaaAA'a'.  a0a1a1aa. a0a1a.aa. a0a1a-aa. 0abc0a-b’c'dfhf.ejg f0a9sdfgjgjgkj"
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @user10118326 ... are there any questions regarding the above approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/^(?!.*(?!\.\s)[\s`'.-]{2})[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.\s`'-]*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hkJal4/1) and the regex graph:

[image].

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?!\.\s)[\s`'.-]{2})`
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9.\s`'-]*`- zero or more (due to`*`) ASCII letters or digits,` .`, whitespace, backtick, singlq straight quotation mark or hyphen chars
- `$` - end of string.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['An abc with 123.', 'An abc with 123...', 'A 123 abc . '];
const re = /^(?!.*(?!\.\s)[\s`'.-]{2})[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.\s`'-]*$/;
for (const text of texts) {
    console.log(text, '=>', re.test(text));
}
```